# LT Spice Transformer Circuit Questions

Tags: voltage, transformer, ltspice, simulation

I'm a TA trying to convert a physical transformer circuit design that uses a transformer kit to an LT Spice simulation for some students who need practice but cannot attend my physical lab due to health concerns.

The physical lab uses a Function Generator set to 20 Vpp and 60 Hz with a 2 to 1 step down transformer. The idea is to use oscilloscope probes to measure voltages at points to determine their transformer kit's parameters. The students have to use Vb to determine the primary side current I1.
[image: Physical Circuit Schematic. Vb is a voltage the students measure to determine primary side current]

I tried implementing this in LT Spice following guides posted in the documentation for LT Spice and was getting the same voltage at point A as I was getting at point B, which I know shouldn't be the case due to the voltage drop across the DC resistance and windings of the primary. I'm getting 20 Volts for the measured voltages at points A and B. I'd really appreciate any advice on how to properly implement this in LT Spice.

[image: LT Spice Simulation Setup. The voltage at Point A is the same as the voltage at point B which I don't want.]

Comment: How does inductance vary with respect to the number of turns of wire?

Comment: Also, what is the output impedance of your function generator? I'm assuming you are saying that the resistance of the transformer as \$100\:\mu\Omega\$ (since that's what you wrote up there) and I'm pretty sure that's not the signal generator's output impedance. But maybe it is?

Comment: Since you haven't responded, I was asking my first question because you mentioned 2:1 as the voltage ratio for your transformer. But this means a difference by a factor of 4 in inductance, literally *by the definition* of the inductance constant and assuming a shared core from using your Spice card. So you've already started off on the wrong foot. The rest isn't important until you get that much right. They are just details. If you are going to ***ever*** get anything like a realistic simulation from your own efforts, you will need to know the basics.

Comment: 1. I'm just trying to model a basic step down transformer without it varying the inductance with respect to turns.
2. The Output Impedance of the Transformer is 1 Mega Ohm. So do you recommend doing a parasitic resistance of 1 mega ohm?
3. I just got back to my computer after a day of teaching a class and assisting students. Yes I'm trying to get a basic step down transformer. I picked the 2 mH to 1 mH from a video I watched for an AC to DC converter. I just want to simulate a step down transformer in LT SPICE

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've been spending the time trying to look up tutorials on how to do this. There isn't a wealth of resources on LT Spice and I thought of asking here.

Comment: Well, you need to realize that the ONLY WAY that LTspice knows the voltage ratio is by the inductance ratio. So if you don't get that part right, nothing else will ever make any sense. Thanks for the reason why you were busy. Got it. I was also in two different Fall Term classes today, also doing teaching. So I get that, as well. But 2 mH to 1 mH is not 2:1 voltage ratio. I worry when folks do that. It means they don't know how to use Spice.

Comment: You have data on actual measurements that do make sense to you. You need to disclose those measurements, now. It will go a long way in helping us help you.

Comment: Ok. So to clarify if I wanted to get a 2 to 1 stepdown transformer do you reccomend using a 4 H to 1 H Primary to Secodnary Inductance? I haven't found alot of resources to properly learn how to use LT Spice and my Undergraduate Education only did a surface level education on how to use LT Spice. I'm trying to teach students how to use it more and was trying to teach myself.

Comment: The circuit diagram I showed above is how the teacher for the class I'm instructing the lab has always done it. I was trying to better understand how to explain how to simulate this type of circuit for the students. We typically use a function generator set to High Z (1M ohm), at 20Vpp, and 60Hz. The 100 ohm resistor typically is in the mV range when the students measure voltage across it. The V2 open circuit is typically 5 to 2 volts. If you have any advice on how to better simulate this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: We need your measurement data. I can't tell you to use 4 H and 1 H, or 400 mH and 100 mH or anything else in particular. Read Andy's answer, for example. The inductance is appropriate for the frequency involved and the power transfer that is expected, as well. Heavy transformers will have larger inductances. In any case, you will need to give us the data you have that is "reasonable" to you. From that, we ***may*** be able to backtrack to Henry values. Maybe. But you don't know what you don't know.. So we have to work with what you have at hand.

Comment: That was VERY IMPORTANT information you just disclosed about your use of the function generator. Thanks!! I think this will help Andy a great deal.

Comment: From the lab's I've run. The voltage Vb is around 500 mV. The open circuit voltage is around 2 volts. These voltages are measured on an oscilloscope using one probe connected to the secondary and tied to it's ground with no load attached to it. The primary has that 100 ohm resistor tied to the opposite side of the transformer kit with a 100 ohm resistor in series before reaching ground on the primary.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information. I'm trying to better learn this for my students so I can better help them. Any help you offer with this will really go a long way for my class. I'm a Masters student and trying to get better at my field through experience.

Comment: Well, one thing that immediately pops to mind is that with a \$1\:\text{M}\Omega\$ output from the function generator and a \$100\:\Omega\$ resistor in series with the primary, there is no possible way of measuring more than about \$2\:\text{mV}\$ peak voltage across the resistor. If you are saying \$500\:\text{mV}\$ is measured (and I'm assuming RMS or something similar, anyway), then there is something already odd about the circumstance.

Comment: Write down as much detail as you can in your question. Include the function generator identification so that we can look up its datasheet information.

Comment: @JetPirate When you write the voltages, write them as Vrms, or Vp, or Vpp. You mentioned 20 Vpp, so you'll have to set up your LTspice source to 10 V (you're setting up the amplitude). You also mentioned "a few mV across R", was that with an open secondary, or loaded? These things need to be mentioned, the devil's in the details. Once you start ennumerating them in writing, it's very possible you'll be able to make your own mental connections.

Comment: Specifications for the Actual Circuit Build (Described in Figure 6):
1. Function Generator: Tektronix AFG3022C Arbitrary/Function Generator
2. Voltage Input to the Circuit: 20 Vpp at 60Hz set to High Impedance/Z
3. Transformer Kit: The kits were all made differently. I'm trying to make an arbitrary transformer example in LT Spice.
Like I said in the explaination of this problem, the voltage across the Vb varies. I looked at my notes and its approximately supposed to be 10 to 25 mV. The secondary side is left open to measure the voltage drop. V2oc is typically 2 Volts.

Comment: @JetPirate Something's wrong: if the source is HighZ (1M) then for (RMS values) \$V_{sec}=2\Rightarrow V_{pri}=4\Rightarrow \frac{Z_{pri}}{R_{in}+100}=\frac{4}{7.07}\approx 565.77k\$. If we assume \$R_{pri}=1k\Rightarrow X_{pri}\approx Z_{in}\Rightarrow L_{pri}=\frac{565k}{2\pi60}\approx1.5k\$. That's 1500 Henry. Also, \$V_R\approx 450\mu\text{V}\$, or more than 20x lower than your lowest estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Your source has a frequency of 60 Hz and your primary inductance is 2 mH which has an impedance of 0.75 ohms at 60 Hz hence, more than 99.9 per cent of the applied voltage appears across the 100 ohm series resistor R2. Try making the primary inductance more like 2 henry if you want to model an AC power transformer. 2 mH is waaaayyyy too small and it gives the impression (although not absolutely true) that A and B voltages are identical.

Comment: Ok sure. I'll try modifying it to a different Inductance. I was following a tutorial video on LT Spice to pick the ratio. I'll try a larger inductance. Thanks.